# Определение inline функции вне класса

Tags: c++, функции, классы, language-lawyer, inline

Является ли функция, определённая вне класса, используя спецификатор `inline`, `inline`? Можно ли в объявлении не использовать `inline`, а в определении - использовать?

```
struct S {
    void foo();
};

inline void S::foo() {}
```

Не могу понять из [документации](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/inline). Там написано про определение внутри класса и то, что нельзя переобъявлять функцию как `inline`, если до этого она была определена как не `inline`.

Comment: а Вам не кажется, что В первой строке содержится логическое противоречие?

Comment: @KoVadim вне класса vs inline? `inline` же не строго означает "внутри класса", так что нет, не кажется

Comment: я думаю, все зависит от того, что Вы понимаете под inline.

Comment: @KoVadim то, что по ссылке приведено - *The inline specifier, when used in a function's decl-specifier-seq, declares the function to be an inline function.* Первый `inline` - спецификатор/ключевое слово, а второй - `inline`-функция

Comment: ну вот собственно Вы сами и ответили на свой вопрос - есть спецификатор inline - это inline функция.

Comment: @KoVadim но там же написано, например, *A function declared constexpr is implicitly an inline function.* Т.е. не только лишь ключевое слово `inline` определяет встраиваемую функцию. Мне непонятно, будет ли в конкретном примере функция `inline`, ведь мы объявили её сначала без `inline` + не определили её внутри класса

Comment: А я где то написал, что отсутствие слова inline делает ее не inline? нет, я об этом не писал. Вывод - Вы или не знаете английского, или юлите.

Comment: @KoVadim так вы можете ответить на вопрос - будет ли в данном примере функция `inline`, не `inline`, UB из-за переобъявления не `inline` функции с `inline` спецификатором?

Comment: Вам же внизу ответили и Вы даже приняли

Comment: @KoVadim ну да, уже после этого комментария. Можете тоже ответить на вопрос, если не согласны с принятым ответом или есть лучшее объяснение

Comment: мне объяснение не нравится (оно не ссылается никуда). Я лично считаю, что подобное Вашему объявления не стоит использовать, хотя я не нашел ни одного подтверждения тому, что этот код невалидный.

Comment: я спросил своих знакомых, которые учувствуют в коммитете по стандартизации. Они сейчас ушли в обсуждение особенностей inline с шаблонами, но собственно по вопросу они не видят проблем, но пока не смогли найти место в стандарте, который бы специфицировал это поведение.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Метод может быть `inline` в 5 случаях:

1. Объявлен c `inline`, затем определен без `inline`:

```
struct S
{
    inline void foo();
};

void S::foo() {}
```

2. Объявлен c `inline`, затем определен c `inline`:

```
struct S
{
    inline void foo();
};

inline void S::foo() {}
```

3. Объявлен без `inline`, затем определен c `inline`:

```
struct S
{
    void foo();
};

inline void S::foo() {}
```

4. Объявлен c `inline` и сразу определен в теле класса:

```
struct S
{
    inline void foo() {}
};
```

5. Объявлен без `inline` и сразу определен в теле класса, который не экспортируется:

```
struct S
{
    void foo() {}
};
```

Если класс экспортируется из модуля, то метод уже не будет `inline`, это стоит иметь ввиду при переводе существующего кода на модули:

```
export module test;

export struct S
{
    void foo() {}
};
```

ЗЫ еще есть шаблоны, но это другая история

Answer (score -1):

Если определение функции_члена выполняется в той же области видимости, что и объявление класса, то она автоматически легко встраивается. Так что:

```
{
    struct S {
        void foo();
    };
    inline void S::foo() {}
}
```

или

```
{
    struct S {
        void foo();
    };
    void S::foo() {}
}
```

или

```
{
    struct S {
        void foo(){}
    };        
}
```

ничем не отличаются.

Comment: Ну 2 и 3 случай точно отличаются из документации

Comment: 2 случай - это точно не  inline

Comment: компиляторы могут свободно использовать встроенную подстановку для любой функции, которая не помечена как встроенная, и могут генерировать вызовы функций для любой функции, помеченной как встроенная. @KoVadim, докажите, что для второго случая не разрешено несколько определений, и я соглашусь, По какой логике она не может быть встроенная, я не пойму.

Comment: да, компилятор может инлайнить и не инлайнить все, что он считает правильным, пока это не нарушает общий ход программы. @ARHovsepyan  - доказать, что можно нарушить ODR?

Comment: Да,  у меня  никак не получается это доказывать Докажете, буду благодарен за инфу.

Comment: есть правило ODR - правило одного определения. В втором случае функция foo может заинлайнится, но вот модификатора inline  у нее нет. В третьем случае модификатор inline есть, но он "неявный". Первый случай как раз и вызвал у вопрошающего вопрос о том, будет ли такой модификатор.

Comment: @KoVadim, вы говорили, что второй случай точно не inline, а теперь говорите, что может заинлайниться...  А я спрашиваю, по какой логике , если в третьем случаи она встроенная, то не встроенная во втором случаи?  Нынче компиляторы встраивают все, что можно встраивать. Это двадцать первый век...Кстати, если в этой функции вызваны, например, виртуальные методы, или по каким то другим причинам  определения, она по любому не будет встроенная, даже если вы объявите как inline

Comment: Вы путаете две штуки - модификатор inline и факт встраивания. Они хоть и рядом, но нет. А вот вызвать виртуальный метод не выйдет (в ввиду отсутствия такого в с++). Но вот вызов вирутальной функции-члена - почему нет.

Comment: @KoVadim, Я говорил как раз о факте встраивания, и если кто то что то путает и хочет доказывать свою правоту, а не  выяснять истину, то это не я...

Comment: тогда Ваш ответ бессмысленный - он не отвечает на вопрос автора

Comment: хорошо, отвечайте только вы, а я буду только пользоваться. Не красиво всеми способами стараться  доказывать свою правоту или нетерпимость _ это не детский сад...

Comment: м, я понимаю Ваше негодование, но автор спрашивал о том, как применяется спецификатор inline. А Ваш ответ заключается в том, может ли функция встраиваться вообще. Подумайте об этом и поймете, что Вы обижаетесь на придуманную собой же проблему.