# Методы класса, определённые прямо в объявлении класса, по умолчанию inline или нет?

Tags: c++, c++11

Есть [header-only](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Header-only) класс, наподобие примера ниже, все методы класса, определённы прямо в объявлении класса.

```
class Class {
public:
    void foo() { /*some super cool code*/ }
};
```

ВОПРОС: Можно ли с уверенностью утверждать, что **все методы такого класса по умолчанию рассматриваются как inline**? И писать ключевое слове inline нет смысла?

P.S.
Ну и да, я хорошо понимаю, что ключевое слово inline - это рекомендация компилятору, а не безусловное правило, на это счет не стоит распыляться в комментах. Суть вопроса выделена жирным.

Прошу внимательно прочитать ВОПРОС перед тем как ответить, и прошу по возможности ссылаться на источники вроде [Черновик стандарта C++](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf) и/или на авторитетную литературу. Спасибо!

Comment: Ключевое слово `inline` уже давно не является даже рекомендацией именно в плане встраивания функции, а имеет совсем другой смысл. С уверенностью можно утверждать, что из этого неполного примера нельзя сказать, являются ли методы `inline` или нет. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1406730/%d0%9e%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-inline-%d1%84%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%b2%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b0/1406751#1406751

Comment: Ну, конечно, можно вкомпилить ее код с локальной меткой в создаваемый объектник, но проще сразу поместить его экземпляр в каждом месте вызова

Comment: @user7860670 Скорее, нельзя сказать, будет встроен код или нет, а `inline` они таки являются.

Comment: Стандарт **N3242=11-0012** / **N3337** / **N3936** `7.1.2 Function specifiers` -`A function defined within a class definition is an inline function.`

Comment: Можно  с уверенностью утверждать, что функции легко встраиваются, если  нет причин не встраивать

Comment: @ar-hovsepyan, спасибо за комментарий - просто и ни о чем!

Comment: @James,  может быть и ни о чем _ это смотря кто слушает и понимает....

Answer (score 3):

Краткий ответ: **да**, методы определённые сразу при объявлении неявно являются **inline**

[cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/inline) говорит, что

> A function defined entirely inside a class/struct/union definition,
> whether it's a member function or a non-member friend function, is
> implicitly an inline function *if it is attached to the global module (since C++20)*.

Перевод:

> Функция, определённая полностью внутри определения class/struct/union,
> независимо от того, является ли она функцией-элементом или friend
> функцией, не являющейся элементом, неявно является встроенной
> функцией, *если она присоединена к глобальному модулю (начиная с*
> *C++20)*.

Из [черновика стандарта](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf) можете открыть:

1. стр. 210 9.3.2:

> A member function may be defined (8.4) in its class definition, in
> which case it is an inline member function

2. стр. 238 первая строчка 11.3.7

Comment: В цитате говорится наоборот, определённые сразу при объявлении методы могут быть `inline`, а могут и не быть, в зависимости от того, является ли класс частью глобального модуля или экспортируется.

Comment: @tim-bars, я намерено поставил тэг C++11, а `since C++20` это другая история. Но все равно спасибо за старания помочь!

Comment: @James , вы видимо не поняли, про `с++20` там только конец о глобальном модуле, всё остальное от `с++20` не зависит

Comment: @user7860670 в цитате говорится что они `inline` неявно, приписка про модуль относится к `с++20`, задающий спрашивает в контексте `с++11`, специально же ещё привёл места в 11 стандарте которые можно открыть чтобы убедиться, что функции будут инлайн